# python 3.x, Alfresco get noderefs in site, cmislib

Tags: python-3.x, alfresco, cmis, nodereference

Hello i need to get noderefs to files in specific site/docLibrary.
I found something but it is not working. 
[sourceOne](https://geofoss.net/2015/08/12/python-cmis-scripts-for-alfresco/),[sourceTwo](https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-api-python-examples)

I use Alfresco Community v5.1.0, python 3.6.1, Windows 10-EclipseNeon2.

Things i found maybe worked in the past but i can't use it, it has trouble with libraries even when i install them.

So can anybody show me some working code to do this in python ?

Comment: How are you writing your code? To run within the Alfresco application on jython? Or outside connecting in with REST services / similar?

Comment: outside and i think i need to use cmislib somehow but i dont know how to import it or use it and i cand find anything about the newest version that is working...

Comment: Start at http://chemistry.apache.org/python/docs/ and follow that? Should work fine!

Comment: that seems nice only thing that troubles me is requirements, where is written python 2.6.x

Comment: i tried to install and import from cmislib, this is what i get:
PS D:\signia\exportImport> py .\repairExpr.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\repairExpr.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cmislib import CmisClient, Repository, Folder
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cmislib-0.5.1-py3.6.egg\cmislib\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'

Comment: cmislib does not yet support Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used python 2.7 and cmislib, these things aren't posible in 3.6